# Unloaded buffers and the :ls! command

Tags: buffers, command

I ran `:ls!` (having only a vague memory of the command and not really knowing what I was going to see) and saw a short list of files (maybe 5 or 6) with 'u' in the gutter. Apart from one of the files, all were from months or years ago.

I understand the 'u' means they are 'unloaded' buffers. Somewhere I read you can get rid of them with `:bwipeout`. So I did that. They disappeared from `:ls!`.

However, shortly after, another file appeared in the `:ls!` list with 'u' in the gutter; a file I think I closed normally. However, other files I've been editing and closing normally like the latter did not appear in the list.

What's going on? Why did *this* file, in no way different from other files I've been editing, appear in the `:ls!` list and others not?

And why are buffers in vim so extraordinarily convoluted? Is there a post anywhere that is able to explain buffers in a short, sweet way?

Comment: `u` is for unlisted buffers, not unloaded

Answer (score 1):

I would go for `:h :ls` for an explanation.

In short, `:ls!` shows also unlisted buffers (`:h unlisted-buffers`) also available as a link from `:h :ls`:

```
                                                *unlisted-buffer*
unlisted        The buffer is not in the buffer list.  It is not used for
                normal editing, but to show a help file, remember a file name
                or marks.  The ":bdelete" command will also set this option,
                thus it doesn't completely delete the buffer.  Settings: >
                        :setlocal nobuflisted
```

If you are sure that buffers you see there were wiped out, not deleted, then I would think of a plugin that set `nobuflisted` for the buffer(s).

Comment: So under what circumstances would a file appear in `:ls!` command upon opening a new gvim window? 

For example, I have been editing, writing, and quitting various files this morning. I have just opened a new gvim window. The `:ls` command lists just one buffer, `[No Name]`. Yet `:ls!` lists an additional buffer, a file that was one of the many files I edited today. In the margin it says, `2u`. I don't believe this file is in any way particularly different from any of the other files I edited today.

Comment: Maybe you had set a global mark?

Comment: I have a mapping to `bunload` a buffer. It appears this makes a buffer appear in `:ls!` commands upon new gvim starts. But only to a maximum of two **unlisted** buffers. Each new `bunload`ed buffers overwrites older in the latter list. 

Is this how it's supposed to work? It seems, slightly (ahem) insane.

Comment: > Maybe you had set a global mark? – Maxim Kim

I don't think so. Are you saying that creating a global mark in a file would make it appear in `:ls!` command for entirely new gvim window?

Comment: well, in my case I don't see any of the unlisted buffers when I start a new gvim. No matter if I `:bunload` it or not.
Does it happen if you start vim without user configuration? `vim -Nu NONE`

Comment: OK, `gvim -Nu NONE` gives no additional buffers with `:ls!` command. I can easily disable plugins by renaming **bundle** (pathogen) folder. This also stops

Comment: I've isolated it to plugin **vim-markbar-master**. I'll update if possible and see.

Comment: Same problem with updated vim-markbar plugin. I've opened an issue. Thanks for your help.